# Add values in two Spark DataFrames, row by row

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark

I have two Spark DataFrames, with values that I would like to add, and then multiply, and keep the lowest pair of values only. I have written a function that will do this:

```
math_func(aValOne, aValTwo, bValOne, bValTwo):
    tmpOne = aValOne + bValOne
    tmpTwo = aValTwo + bValTwo
    final = tmpOne*tmpTwo
    return final
```

I would like to iterate through two Spark DataFrames, "A" and "B", row by row, and keep the lowest values results. So if I have two DataFrames:

```
DataFrameA:
ID | ValOne | ValTwo
0  | 2      | 4
1  | 3      | 6

DataFrameB:
ID | ValOne | ValTwo
0  | 4      | 5
1  | 7      | 9
```

I would like to first take row 0 from DataFrameA:, compare it to rows 0 and 1 of DataFrameB, and then keep the lowest value results. I have tried this:

```
results = DataFrameA.select('ID')(lambda i: DataFrameA.select('ID')(math_func(DataFrameA.ValOne, DataFrameA.ValTwo, DataFrameB.ValOne, DataFrameB.ValOne))
```

but I get errors about iterating through a DataFrame column. I know that in Pandas I would essentially make a nested "for loop", and then just write the results to another DataFrame and append the results. The results I would expect are:

```
Initial Results:
DataFrameA_ID | Value | DataFrameB_ID
0             | 54    | 0 
0             | 117   | 1    
1             | 77    | 0
1             | 150   | 1

Final Results:
DataFrameA_ID | Value | DataFrameB_ID
0             | 54    | 0    
1             | 77    | 0
```

I am quite new at Spark, but I know enough to know I'm not approaching this the right way.

Any thoughts on how to go about this?

Comment: Does this mean if you have `m` rows in A and `n` in B, then you would do m*n operations ? Also can you update your question with expected output as well ?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I understand the computational complexity is a bit high, but I don't see any other way around it.

Comment: @Amit I added in the expected final results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need multiple steps to achieve this.

Suppose you have data

```
DFA:
ID | ValOne | ValTwo
0  | 2      | 4
1  | 3      | 6

DFB:
ID | ValOne | ValTwo
0  | 4      | 5
1  | 7      | 9
```

**Step 1.** 
Do a [cartesian](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/apache-spark-2x/9781787126497/09cd98e2-a458-4e9f-a6f0-56f02cec56aa.xhtml) join on your 2 dataframes. That will give you:

```
Cartesian:
DFA.ID | DFA.ValOne | DFA.ValTwo | DFB.ID | DFB.ValOne | DFB.ValTwo
0      | 2          | 4          | 0      |          4 | 5
1      | 3          | 6          | 0      |          4 | 5 
0      | 2          | 4          | 1      |          7 | 9
1      | 3          | 6          | 1      |          7 | 9
```

**Step 2.**

Multiply columns:

```
    Multiplied:
    DFA.ID | DFA.Mul | DFB.ID | DFB.Mul
    0      | 8       | 0      |     20
    1      | 18      | 0      |     20 
    0      | 8       | 1      |     63
    1      | 18      | 1      |     63
```

**Step 3.**
Group by `DFA.ID` and select min from `DFA.Mul` and `DFB.Mul`

Comment: I think it would be better to add the code you used to achieve this results here. Especially since OP said they are quite new to Spark.

Comment: I actually ended up doing this exact thing independently! Thank you @Vladislav, I am glad that my approach was validated. I appreciate the time and effort to answer my question!